# API/manual for ie4uinit command?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

So, I found that the command to refresh file icons in Windows Explorer is `ie4uinit -show` or `ie4uinit.exe -show`

I wanted to find more on the executable/command, but couldn't find any documentation on the topic.

I tried running:

```
help ie4uinit
ie4uinit -h
ie4uinit --help
ie4uinit /?
```

Neither of them return anything. What is this and where I can find more info on how to use it (specifically what command line switches does it have)?

Google returns nothing but "is ie4uinit a virus?" results

Comment: Going down the rabbit hole to find anything... [reddit - win 10 tech supp](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10TechSupport/comments/hc2jjk/whats_ie4uinitexe/) -> [file.net - ie4uinit.exe](https://www.file.net/process/ie4uinit.exe.html) -> [wikipedia - Active Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Setup)

Comment: wikipedia -> [only citation: a blogpost about active setup](https://helgeklein.com/blog/active-setup-explained/) -> [google search for relationship between active setup and ie](https://www.google.com/search?q=active+setup+internet+explorer)

Comment: google -> [news article from 1997 about Active Setup debut with ie4](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/microsoft-reportedly-debuts-active-setup-first-ie-4-beta-test)

Comment: What *Windows version* are you trying to run that command in?

Comment: @JorgeLuiz Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

> it performs operations on the Icon Cache Database, a hidden ".db"-type file in the "%userprofile%\AppData\Local" subdirectory, determined by command-line switches including "-BaseSettings", "-UserIconConfig", "-ClearIconCache", or "-Reinstall." (In Win10 its switches differ.)

---

From [What is ie4uinit.exe?](https://www.file.net/process/ie4uinit.exe.html)

> The genuine *ie4uinit.exe* file is a software component of *Internet Explorer* by *Microsoft Corporation*.
>
> "Ie4uinit.exe" is a [Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft) utility program having both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The version matching the machine resides in "C:\Windows\System32". On 64-bit machines the 32-bit version is also run from "C:\Windows\SysWOW64". Called the "Internet Explorer Per-User Initialization Utility," it performs operations on the Icon Cache Database, a hidden ".db"-type file in the "%userprofile%\AppData\Local" subdirectory, determined by command-line switches including "-BaseSettings", "-UserIconConfig", "-ClearIconCache", or "-Reinstall." (In Win10 its switches differ.) The Icon Cache retains copies of icons being used by Windows or IE to avoid repeatedly redrawing them. Most often "ie4uinit.exe" runs during Active Setup, where Windows detects at user login whether a user's profile lacks certain registry subkeys in the Current User (HKCU) hive that exist in the Local Machine (HKLM) hive, performs specific functions, and then puts those subkeys in HKCU to prevent repetition. This is an essential tool in enterprise installations with many endpoints.

and

> The process known as IE Per-User Initialization Utility or IE-Hilfsprogramm für Pro-Benutzerinitalisierung or Utilitaire d'initialisation d'Internet Explorer par utilisateur or Utilità di inizializzazione Per utente di Internet Explorer belongs to software Internet Explorer or Windows Internet Explorer by Microsoft ([www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com)).
>
> **Description**: The original ie4uinit.exe is an important part of Windows and rarely causes problems. The file ie4uinit.exe is located in the C:\Windows\System32 folder. Known file sizes on Windows 10/8/7/XP are 188,416 bytes (33% of all occurrences), 176,128 bytes or 749,056 bytes.
>
> The file is a Windows system file. The program is not visible. Ie4uinit.exe is a Microsoft signed file. Therefore the technical security rating is 10% dangerous.